# Prove $L(f\cdot g) = L(f) + L(g)$ for two differentiable positive functions $f,g: I \to \mathbb{R}$ with $L(f):= \frac{f^{-1}}{f}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, logarithms

For a differentiable, positive function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ we look at the logarithmic function, i.e.,

$$L(f): I \to \mathbb{R} \text{ with } L(f):= \frac{f^{-1}}{f}$$

Prove, that for two differentiable functions $f,g: I \to \mathbb{R}$, the following equality holds:

$$L(f\cdot g) = L(f) + L(g)$$

I would have proven it as follows, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions and $y = f(x)g(x)$.

Then $\ln y = \ln(f(x)g(x)) = \ln f(x) + \ln g(x)$.

Then $\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$

So,

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y \bigl( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \bigr) \\
= f(x)g(x) \bigl( \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \bigr) \\
= f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x)$$

The problem I have is that I believe that the question asks for a proof of the logarithmic product rule, but the notation of $L(f) := \frac{f^{-1}}{f}$ is confusing me because it stands for the inverse function. Is it actually asking for something else?

Comment: You say this is about a logarithmic product rule, and that $f,g$ need to be differentiable, but $L(f)$ does not reference $f'$ in any way. Are you sure about the statement of the problem?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer No. I just assumed it was about the logarithmic product rule because we are looking at the $\log$ function and the equality reminded me of it

Comment: The logarithmic derivative of $f$ is defined as $f'/f$.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I just looked it up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative. So there's nothing wrong with the proof?

Comment: If you mean to show that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x) \cdot g(x)) =\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x))+\frac{d}{dx} \ln(g(x))$, then the result follows from the product rule for logarithmic expressions and the linearity of differentiation.

Comment: If logarithmic derivative is defined by $f'/f$, then it makes sense even if $f$ is negative; so try to prove your formula without mentioning logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you are misreading the text or it is a typo. The logarithmic derivative is defined by $L(f)=(\ln f)'$, where $f'$ means the derivative of $f$, which equals $f'/f$.

If you try to check $(f\cdot g)^{-1}/(f\cdot g)=f^{-1}/f+g^{-1}/g$ where $f^{-1}$ means inverse function, you will fail because this is not true. Counterexamples are easy, e.g. $f(x)=g(x)=x$ on $(0,\infty)$.